# How to debug the network stack in linux

Tags: linux, network-programming

I am trying to inject a packet into the network using raw sockets, but somehow can't seem to get a receiver to capture this packet. How do i check whether the packet is being dropped by the linux network stack? Could someone point out some tools for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about accessing the network stack directly (not saying it's impossible, just that I don't know how to do it if you can), but you could probably use Wireshark or something similar to see if the NIC on the receiving end is receiving the packets. You could also use it on the sending end to check if the packets are being sent out properly (or are actually being sent out in the first place, if that's the issue), as it allows you to examine the fields/etc. of individual packets. Quite a useful tool, really.

http://www.wireshark.org/

Note that the website doesn't have direct downloads for Linux builds, but does list third-party packages for various Linux distros.

Answer (score 1):

Options include wireshark and tcpdump, or tcpdumping into a pcap file and then analyzing that using wireshark. One option probably is also to use strace or similar tool  to trace the system calls that do the sending.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [BPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter) to instrument the TCP stack in the kernel. You can take a look at some of the already existent scripts for TCP, e.g. tcplife:

- https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/tcplife.py
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/tcplife-bpfcc.8.html
- http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2016-11-30/linux-bcc-tcplife.html